# TER Occitanie ticket pricing at station vs online

Tags: trains, tickets, france, sncf

I'm planning a return trip from Latour-de-Carol to Toulouse next week. Prices for next week on SNCF Connect are higher (~25 euros per single trip) than further in the future (starting at just 10 euros).

I know that with TER trains it is also possible to purchase a ticket at the station at the day of travelling, but what will the price be there? Will it be the highest possible online fare, or is it a lower, standard fare? The possibility to purchase tickets at stations is widely mentioned online, but have not been able to find information on the pricing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The possibility to purchase tickets at stations is widely mentioned online, but have not been able to find information on the pricing.

Pricing will be the exact same at a station and through SNCF Connect, since for TER prices are set by regions and not by dynamic pricing like TGV would.

> Prices for next week on SNCF Connect are higher (~25 euros per single trip) than further in the future (starting at just 10 euros).

On the same exact train? Because there are some [saver fares](https://www.ter.sncf.com/occitanie/tarifs-cartes/petits-prix) that are sometimes implemented.

If you book >= 10 days in advance, some tickets may pop up at [€1](https://www.ter.sncf.com/occitanie/tarifs-cartes/billets-un-euro)

For some trains in the region ([listed on the TER site](https://www.ter.sncf.com/occitanie/tarifs-cartes/petits-prix/fute)), another type of fixed pricing is implemented

> - 3€ <= 40 km
> - 5€ >= 41 < 80 km
> - 10€ >= 81 < 200 km
> - 15€ >= 200 km

If you travel on the first weekend of the month [all tickets cost €1](https://www.ter.sncf.com/occitanie/tarifs-cartes/bons-plans/premier-week-end-un-euro)

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for you reply. And for the info that the pricing is the same at the stations. I see now that indeed, the exact same trains have the same (high-ish) prices at a given weekday and time. My mistake. It appears the train I need to take always costs €28,10, even if other trains the same day cost only 10 (or indeed 1 on specific weekends or timeslots). A surprising difference.

Comment: @Quan 28.10 is the normal fare, and 10/1 are promotional fares